# How to read array from text file?

Tags: php, arrays

I have stored array in txt file using file_put_contents() in php, php array write successfullu in text file as same time how to read that text file into php?

```
<?php
$arr = array('name','rollno','address');
file_put_contents('array.txt', print_r($arr, true));
?>
```

The above php write text file in successfully. i want read that text file in php?

Comment: don't use `print_r` use `var_export` instead

Comment: what is the diff b/w those two var_export and print_r ?

Comment: if you plan on reusing those values from the array, you'd better of using `var_export` or just create a json file

Comment: i have used var_export and then use `$strarray = file_get_contents('input_array_export.txt');` and my input_array_export.txt contain `array ( 'select' => array ( 189 => array ( 'vl' => array ( 0 => '2', 1 => '1', )` and then i have tried to `print_r($strarray['select']);` it has return `a`

Comment: how i can access `select` index from readed array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you plan on reusing those same values inside the array, you could use `var_export` on creating that array file instead.

Basic example:

```
$arr = array('name','rollno','address');
file_put_contents('array.txt',  '<?php return ' . var_export($arr, true) . ';');
```

Then, when the time comes to use those values, just use `include`:

```
$my_arr = include 'array.txt';
echo $my_arr[0]; // name
```

Or just use a simple `JSON` string, then encode / decode:

```
$arr = array('name','rollno','address');
file_put_contents('array.txt',  json_encode($arr));
```

Then, when you need it:

```
$my_arr = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.txt'), true);
echo $my_arr[1]; // rollno
```

Comment: Thank u, i got Expected result, but i have doubt from `'<?php return ' . var_export($InputArr, true) . ';'` why we use return  i don't know can you explain

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
$arr = file('array.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try to read the file as below

```
$strarray = file_get_contents('array.txt');
```

Then you can use the array as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

**fopen()**

The first parameter of fopen() contains the name of the file to be opened and the second parameter specifies in which mode the file should be opened

**fread()**

The first parameter of fread() contains the name of the file to read from and the second parameter specifies the maximum number of bytes to read.

**fclose()**

The fclose() function is used to close an open file.

```
$arr = array('name','rollno','address');
file_put_contents('array.txt', print_r($arr, true));

$myfile = fopen("array.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("array.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => name [1] => rollno [2] => address )
```