# Append array entry to php file that returns an array

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a file that looks like

```
<?php
return [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    ...
];
```

and I have to append an array entry to this file. At the end it should look like

```
<?php
    return [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
        'key3' => 'value3'
    ];
```

I read the original array by

```
$tmp_array = include 'path_to_file'
```

and append a new entry by

```
$tmp_array["key3"] = "value3;
```

But how do I store it back into the file, so that it looks like mentioned above.

Regards

Comment: You can try array push to add a value to the end of an array.

Comment: do you have any problem if you store data and read as json format ?

Comment: what is the extension of your file that has the array? If it is just a .txt file then this could be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604135/1138192

Comment: You have stored this in a txt file? return [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    ...
];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use var_export function for that**

```
<?php

$tmp_array = include 'file_1.php';
$tmp_array["key3"] = "value3";
file_put_contents("file_1.php","<?php\nreturn ".var_export($tmp_array, true).";\n?>");

?>
```

Its working for me

Before:

```
<?php
    return [
      'key1' => 'value1',
      'key2' => 'value2',
    ];
    ?>
```

After:

```
<?php
return array (
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => 'value3',
);
?>
```